# About the existence of primitive root modulo prime

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, primitive-roots

I was reading the theorem about the existence of an integer $t$, the primitive root modulo prime. The proof seemed a bit confusing. I mean the construction part. Why did not they immediately take $t = xy$ instead of $t = x^{m'}y^{m}$? I think $xy$ also satisfies the requirements. Thanks in advance. Here is the link of the proof:

http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~scott/blair/Proof_Theorem_5.html#B

Comment: I think you can write down a quick sketch here and underline the problem that you want to ask to be more precise. It would help you to get an answer quickly. :)

Comment: That's very difficult to read. I suspect though that $xy$ need not necessarily work.

Comment: I will make things easier here. So I have an integer $x$ and $d$ is the smallest integer such that $x^{d} \equiv 1$ (mod p). We have another integer $y$ and the smallest integer $e$ such that $y^{e} \equiv 1$ (mod p). Then We want to construct an integer $t$ for which$f = LCM(d, e)$ is the smallest integer such that $t^{f} \equiv 1$ (mod p). That is what I got from there. So what if we take $t =  xy$? $x^{k} \equiv 1$ (mod p) if and only if $k$ is a multiple of $d$ and $y^{l} \equiv 1$ (mod p) if and only if $l$ is divisible by $e$. So $LCM(d, e)$ really satisfies the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Generally it is not true that in an abelian group that if $\,x,y\,$ have order $\,j,k\,$ then $xy$ has order $\,{\rm lcm}(j,k),\,$ e.g. consider the case $\,y = x^{-1}.\,$ But it is true that there exists *some* element of order $\,{\rm lcm}(j,k),\,$ and this is what is proved there (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10616/242) for a few other proofs of *order lcm-closure*)

**Remark** $ $ Their proof can be simplified. By [here:](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3083157/242) $ $ if $\,x,y\,$ have order $\,d,e\,$ then there are coprime $\,m',m\in \Bbb N\,$ with $\,(d,e)={m'}\,{m},\ (d/m',\,e/m)=1\,$ so $\,x^{\large m'},\, y^{\large m}$ have *coprime* orders $\,d/m',\, e/m\,$ [therefore](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803221/242) their product has order $\ (d/m')(e/m) = de/(d,e) = {\rm lcm}(d,e)$.

Unlike many proofs, the linked proof does not require expensive prime factorization. Instead it employs only gcds so it yields an *efficient algorithm* to compute $\,m',m.$

Comment: Note: I checked the outline of the cited proof but I did not verify its correctness.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, as I understood their proof is complicated because of the formal correctness reasons from the point of view of group theory? However, in this case $xy$ works but such reasoning could fail in some similar situations?

Comment: @shotakobakhidze Why do you believe that $xy$ works?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I realized that it is incorrect if in some step I have only left $y$ which is inverse of $x$ and that fails as you mentioned. Then the answer for them is not $LCM(d, e)$ but 1. Nice point.

Comment: @shota kobakhidze: The author avoids the issue of $y$ being the inverse of $x$ by choosing $y$ so that the order of $y$ doesn't divide $d$. Since the equation $x^d=1$ has at most $d$ solutions, such a choice is always possible (assuming $d < p-1$, we have $d\le{\large{\frac{p-1}{2}}}$).

Comment: Yes, even it is not necessary $y$ to be an inverse of $x$ to fail my assumption. Even if $x^{k}$ is inverse of $y^{k}$ , $k < LCM(d, e)$, my assumption easily fails in this case too.

Comment: @quasi Yes, my point was merely to give a quick simple example where the general claim fails in order to nudge the OP to debug their argument. It is easy to exhibit other counterexamples once one knows that it fails in general.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x\in \{1,...,p-1\}$, and let $d$ be the order of $x$.

If $d=p-1$, then $x$ is a primitive root, and we're done.

Suppose $d < p-1$.

The plan is to find some element of $t\in\{1,...,p-1\}$ whose order exceeds $d$, and then iterate, using $t$ as the new $x$.

As the author argues, there exists $y\in\{1,...,p-1\}$ whose order doesn't divide $d$.

Let $e$ be the order of $y$.

If $e > d$, we can let $t=y$.

Since $e\not\mid d$, we can't have $e=d$.

Suppose $e < d$.

Your claim is that we can let $t=xy$.

Unfortunately, this doesn't always work.

As you correctly observed, since $e\not\mid d$, we get $\text{gcd}(d,e) < e$, hence
$$
\text{lcm}(d,e)
=
\frac{de}{\text{gcd}(d,e)}
=
d\left(\frac{e}{\text{gcd}(d,e)}\right) > d
$$
Let $f$ be the order of $xy$.

Clearly $f{\,|\,}\bigl(\text{lcm}(d,e)\bigr)$.

However, noting Bill Dubuque's post, and correcting my earlier answer, it's not automatic that $f=\text{lcm}(d,e)$.

In fact, we can't even claim $f > d$.

As an example, letting $p=31,x=7,y=23$, we get

- $x$ has order $d=15$.$\\[4pt]$

  $y$ has order $e=10$.$\\[4pt]$

  $xy$ has order $f=6$.

This shows that your idea of using $xy$ for the next iteration doesn't always work.

Comment: Well, the main idea is to show that $f>d$. Then we can take $t$ instead of $x$ do the same things and got another $t'$ with $f'>f$. finally we will get the degree equal to $ p - 1$ it is the maximal possible value for that. So is it correct in this case?

Comment: But the point is that for the originally chosen $x,y$, you don't know that $xy$ is a primitive root.

Comment: I don't say that $xy$ will be a primitive root. I just say that $xy$ has a higher minimal degree $f$ such that $xy^{f} \equiv 1$ (mod p) than $x$.

Comment: $LCM(d, e) * GCD(d, e) = de$ we have $GCD(d, e) < e$ , so $LCM(d, e) > d$. If $LCM(d, e) $ is not equal to $p - 1$, I can take $t$ in place of $x$. why can I do it again this for $t$? the same reason why I could do for $x$. I just don't see what can interfere with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95871/discussion-between-shota-kobakhidze-and-quasi).

Comment: Sorry, I'll come back to this later.

Comment: Thanks for reading the proof. :)

Comment: @shota kobakhidze: My corrected answer gives an example to show why $xy$ is not always good enough.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it. It was a naive assumption from me.

Comment: Sorry for agreeing with your claim too quickly (I was in a rush and was careless). Bill Dubuque's post alerted me to my error (and yours!).