# Order of elements in $\Bbb Z_{24}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What elements of $\Bbb Z_{24}$ are order $2$? Order $3$? Order $4$? Order $6$?

Order $2: 12$

Order $3: 8,16$

Order $4: 6,18$

Order $6: 4$

I had listed element $20$ as order $6$, but erased it late at night. A week later, I can't for the life of me remember why I didn't include it.

Am I correct or incorrect (and why) that element $20$ is order $6$?

Comment: Testing multiples of $20$ up to the sixth should be very fast, and probably take less time than composing this post. Another possibility is to observe that in this group $20=-4$, and to use the fact that a multiple of $4$ is divisible by $24$ if and only if the same multiple of $-4$ is divisible by $24$.

Comment: As a check $\,20 = 8 + 12\,$. The summands have orders $\,3,2\,$ [hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803221/242) $20$ has order $3\cdot 2\ \ $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can brute force calculate:
\begin{align*}
20 \cdot 1 \equiv 20 \mod 24 \\
20 \cdot 2 \equiv 16 \mod 24 \\
20 \cdot 3 \equiv 12 \mod 24 \\
20 \cdot 4 \equiv 8 \mod 24 \\
20 \cdot 5 \equiv 4 \mod 24 \\
20 \cdot 6 \equiv 0 \mod 24 \\
\end{align*}

So the first (positive) multiple of $20$ that produces the group identity $0$ is $6$. Therefore that is the order of $20$.

For bigger calculations in the future, you can instead remember this formula:

The order of any element $k \in \Bbb Z_n$ of the cyclic group with $n \in \Bbb N$ elements is
$$
\boxed{\text{ord}(k) = \frac{n}{\gcd(k, n)}}
$$ In this case, $n = 24$ and $k = 20$ and the greatest common divisor of $20$ and $24$ is $\gcd(20, 24) = 4$. So $\text{ord}(k) = \frac{24}{4} = 6$ as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Let the order of $20$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{24}$ be $k$. Then 
$$\underbrace{20+20+\dotsb+20}_{k}=20k \equiv 0  \pmod{24}.$$
This is same as saying $5k \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$. Since $\gcd(5,6)=1$, thus $k \equiv 0 \pmod{6}$, which gives $k=6$.

Answer (score 2):

Definition. Let $\bar x \in \mathbb Z_A$. Then
$\langle \bar x \rangle = \{n \bar x: n \in \mathbb Z \}$ is the subgroup of 
$\mathbb Z_A$ generated by $\bar x$.

The following statements are true.

If $g \mid A$, then 
$\langle \bar g \rangle = 
   \left\{\bar 0, \ \bar g, \ 2\bar g, \ 3\bar g, \ \dots , \ 
   \left( \dfrac Ag - 1\right) \bar g \right\}$. Hence the order of $g$ is 
$\dfrac Ag$.

Let $\bar x \in \mathbb Z_A$ and let 
$g = \gcd\{x, A\}$. Then $\langle \bar x \rangle = \langle \bar g \rangle$. Hence
the order of $x$ is $\dfrac{A}{\gcd\{x,A\}}.$

Proof. Let $y \in \langle \bar x \rangle$. Then $y = nx$ for some integer $n$. Since $g \mid x$, then $x = mg$ for some integer $m$. So $y = nx = (nm)g$. 
Hence $\bar y \in \langle \bar g \rangle$. So 
$\langle \bar x \rangle \subseteq \langle \bar g \rangle$.

Let $\bar y \in \langle \bar g \rangle$. Then $y = mg$ for some integer $m$.
Since $g = \gcd\{x, A\}$, then there exists integers $u$ and $v$ such that 
$g = ux + vA$. S0 $y = mg = (mu)x + (mv)A$. It follows that 
$y \equiv (mu)x \pmod A$. Hence $y \in \langle \bar x \rangle$ and 
$\langle \bar g \rangle \subseteq \langle \bar x \rangle$. $\blacksquare$

The divisors of $24$ are $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24\}$.

\begin{array}{c|c}
\operatorname{ord} \bar x & x \pmod{24}\\
\hline
1 & 0 \\
2 &  12\\
3 &  8, 16\\
4 & 6, 18\\
6 & 4, 20\\
8 & 3, 9, 15, 21\\
12 & 2, 10, 14, 22\\
24 & 1, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23 \\
\hline
\end{array}

---

$$\gcd(0,24)=24$$
$$ \operatorname{ord}(\bar 0) = \dfrac{24}{24}=1$$
$$ \langle \bar 0 \rangle = \{ \bar 0 \}$$
$$(\text{$1$ element})$$

---

$$ \gcd(12,24)=12$$
$$ \operatorname{ord}(\bar{12}) = \dfrac{24}{12}=2 $$
$$ \langle \bar{12} \rangle = \{ \bar 0, \bar{12} \}$$
$$(\text{$2$ elements})$$

---

$$\gcd(8,24)=\gcd(16,24)=8$$
$$\operatorname{ord}(\bar{8}) = 
   \operatorname{ord}(\bar{16}) = \dfrac{24}{8}=3$$
$$\langle \bar{8} \rangle = 
\langle \bar{16} \rangle = \{ \bar 0, \bar{8}, \bar{16} \}$$
$$(\text{$3$ elements})$$

---

$$\gcd(6,24)=\gcd(18,24)=6$$
$$\operatorname{ord}(\bar{6}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{18}) = \dfrac{24}{6}=4$$ 
$$\langle \bar{6} \rangle = 
\langle \bar{18} \rangle = \{ \bar 0, \bar{6}, \bar{12}, \bar{18} \}$$
$$(\text{$4$ elements})$$

---

$$\gcd(4,24)=\gcd(20,24)=4$$
$$\operatorname{ord}(\bar{4}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{20}) = \dfrac{24}{4}=6$$
$$\langle \bar{4} \rangle = 
\langle \bar{20} \rangle = 
\{ \bar 0, \bar{4}, \bar{8}, \bar{12}, \bar{16}, \bar{20} \}$$
$$(\text{$6$ elements})$$

---

$$\gcd(3,24)=\gcd(9,24)=\gcd(15,24)=\gcd(21,24)=3$$
$$\operatorname{ord}(\bar{3}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{9}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{15}) =
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{21}) =
  \dfrac{24}{3}=8$$
$$\langle \bar{3} \rangle = 
  \langle \bar{9} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{15} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{21} \rangle =
\{ \bar 0, \bar{3}, \bar{6}, \bar{9}, \bar{12}, \bar{15}, 
     \bar{18}, \bar{21} \}$$
$$(\text{$8$ elements})$$

---

$$\gcd(2,24)=\gcd(10,24)=\gcd(14,24)=\gcd(22,24)=2$$
$$\operatorname{ord}(\bar{2}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{10}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{14}) =
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{22}) =
  \dfrac{24}{2}=12$$
$$\langle \bar{2} \rangle = 
  \langle \bar{10} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{14} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{22} \rangle =
\{ \bar 0,   \bar{2},  \bar{4},  \bar{6},  \bar{8},  \bar{10},
   \bar{12}, \bar{14}, \bar{16}, \bar{18}, \bar{20}, \bar{22} \}$$
$$(\text{$12$ elements})$$

---

$$\gcd(1,24)=\gcd(5,24)=\gcd(7,24)=
  \gcd(11,24)=\gcd(13,24)=\gcd(17,24)=\gcd(19,24)=1$$
$$\operatorname{ord}(\bar{1}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{5}) = 
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{7}) =
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{11}) =
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{13}) =
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{17}) =
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{19}) =
  \operatorname{ord}(\bar{23}) =
  \dfrac{24}{1}=24$$
$$\langle \bar{1} \rangle = 
  \langle \bar{5} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{7} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{11} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{13} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{17} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{19} \rangle =
  \langle \bar{23} \rangle =$$
$$\{ \bar 0,   \bar 1    \bar{2},  \bar 3,   \bar{4},  \bar 5,
   \bar{6},  \bar 7,   \bar{8},  \bar 9,   \bar{10},
   \bar{11}, \bar{12}, \bar{13}, \bar{14}, \bar{15},
   \bar{16}, \bar{17}, \bar{18}, \bar{19}, \bar{20}, 
   \bar{21}, \bar{22}, \bar{23} \}$$
$$(\text{$24$ elements})$$

---

Comment: The last two rows in your table cannot be correct (they must have an even number of elements, being closed under negation).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks. I fixed it.